# c# WPF app sending message using SKYPE4COMLib, but message is not delivered until recipient open app

Tags: c#, wpf, skype, sendmessage, skype4com

I am trying to use SKYPE4COM to send message from a WPF app to iPhone Skype app.

Have done those things:

1. Install Skype 7.17 in OS Windows 10.
2. Register SKYPE4COM component.
3. Add reference to WPF project. (VS2013)
4. Send message this way:

   Skype skype = new Skype();
   skype.Attach(skype.Protocol, true);
   skype.SendMessage("lucy", "Hello, how are you?");

My issue:

Once I send Message through a button click, the message "Hello, how are you?" is shown at the chat window, but it is always showing sending status, not delivered. Please see below print screen. (Message will be delivered once recipient opens Skype app on iPhone ).

[image]

I try to send a message in Skype software instead of my WPF app, the message was sent right away. And the recipient got notification on the iPhone right away. Like this (Please see the second message, was delivered right away)

[image]

I am not sure whether I did something wrong in my WPF code or the skype4COMlib is not working with Skype 7.17 version?

Did a lot researches and only get this 
http://blogs.skype.com/2013/11/06/feature-evolution-and-support-for-the-skype-desktop-api/

Anyone experiences this issue and has a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same library and code you provided.

When I attached to Skype it showed me a notification with the following link:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12384/how-does-my-3rd-party-application-work-with-skype-and-how-will-changes-to-skype-impact-my-3rd-party-application

According to this FAQ entry (which contains the link you have in your question as well):

> As communicated in this blog post, due to technology improvements we are making to the Skype experience, some features of the API will stop working with Skype for desktop. For example, delivery of chat messages using the API will cease to work.

So it really seems it's not possible to send messages using this library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to give up the "chart" option here. Tried Call call = skype.PlaceCall("SkypeID"); for a video call, only work once, then stop working. Tried Call call = skype.PlaceCall("+1xxxxxxxxxx"); with phone number, seems working stably.